# Ext.Template is not defined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm having trouble preparing my application for deployment. I'm using ext-dev.js and have a compnent with the following:

```
Ext.define(myNameSpace.myComponentName, {
    requires: ['Ext.XTemplate'],
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('someTemplate')
})
```

On application startup it gives an

> Ext.XTemplate is not a constructor

Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define Ext.XTemplate inline because it hasn't been retrieved from the server yet by the Ext.Loader which handles loading of dependencies. There are two solutions:

```
// If you really want to add it to the prototype, but adding objects to the 
// prototype is usually a bad idea since they are shared by all instances 
// In this case, it may be ok, since there isn't much you can change about a
// template after you create it
Ext.define('myNameSpace.myComponentName', {
    requires: ['Ext.XTemplate'],
}, function() {
   // This callback is for when all the dependencies are loaded
   myNameSpace.myComponentName.prototype.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('someTemplate')
});

// Or just define it in initComponent, since you shouldn't instantiate it
// until after Ext.onReady is called (which means all dependencies are loaded)
Ext.define('myNameSpace.myComponentName', {
    requires: ['Ext.XTemplate'],
    initComponent: function() {
       this.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('someTemplate');
       this.callParent();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE** I actually forgot to list another possibility that may work, that is, don't use `new`, use `Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', args)'`. The problem with `Ext.create` is that it will block  until `Ext.XTemplate` (and dependencies) is loaded. I would still go with one of two approaches mentioned at the top